# как сформировать многомерный массив из data данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

как сформировать многомерный массив как в var example обходя доступные данные вот в этом простом примере ?

```js
var example = [
  ['Watson', -35.23862, 149.15438],
  ['Waramanga', -35.35276, 149.06042],
  ['Weston', -35.34137, 149.05229],
  ['Manly Beach', -35.56974, 149.13567]
];


var regionPoint = $(".bl_alltown__link");

var fullMark = [],
  myMarkers = [];

regionPoint.map(function() {
  return myMarkers.push($(this).data("sity"), $(this).data("lattitude"), $(this).data("longitude"));
}).get();

console.log("myMarkers =" + myMarkers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bl_alltown">
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Watson" data-lattitude="-35.23862" data-longitude="149.15438" href="">Watson</a></li>
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Waramanga" data-lattitude="-35.35276" data-longitude="149.06042" href="">Waramanga</a></li>
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Weston" data-lattitude="-35.34137" data-longitude="149.05229" href="">Weston</a></li>
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Williamsdale" data-lattitude="-35.56974" data-longitude="149.13567" href="">Williamsdale</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как в массив myMarkers получить такое же отображение данных как и в example ?

Comment: все что внутри `push` оберните в массив `psuh( [ ... ] )`

Comment: не сработало, валит синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: дак исправьте ее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myMarkers = $("a.bl_alltown__link").map(function() {
                     return [ [
                         $(this).data("sity"), 
                         $(this).data("lattitude"), 
                         $(this).data("longitude")
                       ] ];
                  }).get();

console.log( myMarkers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bl_alltown">
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Watson" data-lattitude="-35.23862" data-longitude="149.15438" href="">Watson</a></li>
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Waramanga" data-lattitude="-35.35276" data-longitude="149.06042" href="">Waramanga</a></li>
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Weston" data-lattitude="-35.34137" data-longitude="149.05229" href="">Weston</a></li>
  <li class="bl_alltown__item"><a class="bl_alltown__link" data-sity="Williamsdale" data-lattitude="-35.56974" data-longitude="149.13567" href="">Williamsdale</a></li>
</ul>
```